# "FBDialogs" not available in my app

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I am trying to integrate Facebook sdk in my iOS app. I am using the Facebook reference docs and according to it, I am sharing using FBDialogs but the editor returns error "use of undeclared identifier FBDialogs". I have imported the Facebook sdk, other necessary frameworks, and other obvious things but still not getting it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Finally got what the problem was. It was because of incomplete Facebook sdk. After downloading it several times, finally got the one with all the headers in it.

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you need to add the Framework to the project, but you need to also ensure that the compiler can see the header files.

Add this to the top of the file where you are getting the compiler error.

```
#import "FBDialogs.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to explicitly import FBDialogs. But you absolutely do need to:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

in the .h files of any and all of classes you've created to manage / access your FB connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the SDK version used and **[see in this change log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858488/fbdialogs-not-available-in-my-app)** if it is available to the version you are using.

Hope it helps!